# Find : $ dy/dx, y=\sqrt{4x^2 - 7x - 2}$

Tags: calculus

The problem says Find $dy/dx,  y=\sqrt{4x^2 - 7x - 2}$

So far I changed it to $(4x^2 - 7x - 2)^{1/2}$
I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use [implicit differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function) --- the others seem to assume you know the Chain Rule so no point going down that route (although I use it here).

$$\begin{align}
y(x)&=\sqrt{4x^2-7x-2}
\\ \Rightarrow [y(x)]^2&=4x^2-7x-2.
\end{align}$$
Now I will use the [Chain Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) on the LHS while I differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$\begin{align}
2\cdot y(x)\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}&=8x-7
\\ \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{8x-7}{2y(x)}
\\&=\frac{8x-7}{2\sqrt{4x^2-7x-2}}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I was taught to use the chain rule for this, but only learned it for about 30 minutes in class a few days ago so I am still not 100% clear on the chain rule although I somewhat understand it. For this instance however, will the denominator always be 2 times the square root? Then find the derivative of the square root and that is the numerator?

Comment: Little made up rules like that won't let you get anywhere. The chain rule says that when you are differentiating $u\circ v(x)=u(v(x))$ the derivative is $u'(v(x))\cdot v'(x)$. Not in this answer, but others, the role of $u(x)$ is played by $x^{1/2}$. Now the Chain Rule says differentiate this, input $v(x)=4x^2-7x-2$ and then multiply by the derivative of $v(x)$ which is $8x-7$... do you know the derivative of $u(x)=x^{1/2}$???

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Use the chain rule: $\sqrt{u(x)}' = \dfrac{u'(x)}{2\sqrt{u(x)}}$

Comment: Does this mean I take the derivative of what is in the square root, then divide by 2 times the original?

Comment: ...this is a poor answer because it doesn't extend very well to other scenarios... he clearly doesn't know the change [sic] rule.

Answer (score 0):

$$
y = u^{1/2},\qquad u = 4x^2-7x-2,\qquad \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $y = \sqrt{4x^2 - 7x - 2}$
then 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}(4x^2 - 7x - 2)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\\
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}(4x^2 - 7x - 2) \times (4x^2 - 7x - 2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}
$$
$$
= \frac{8x-7}{2\sqrt{4x^2 - 7x - 2}}
$$

using the chain rule.

That is, if we have a function $y = u^{\frac{1}{2}}$ then $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\times\frac{du}{dx}$$